# Using paypal buy now custom variables

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've got an order page with a single Buy Now button. After a user orders using this button, I'd like to redirect him back to my page with some custom message. For this I'd like to pass his userid to PayPal and get it back.

I've found that I can use custom fields - but didn't understand how I use it and how I get it back.

Could anyone please help? maybe post some code snippet to understand how to build the custom variable and how I get it back.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe post some code on what you've done so far?

Comment: You should post some code about what you've already done, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many [custom fields and variables](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) that you can define when using Website Payments Standard. You can use things like 'custom', 'invoice', 'item_number', 'on0/os0'(through on6/os6) etc..

For the actual PayPal products you would use, check out PayPal's [Order Management Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf).

There is also some great information located within PayPal's MTS (Merchant Technical Services) knowledgebase at [www.paypal.com/mts](http://www.paypal.com/mts). The particular article you will find useful is '[Order Management Automation](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/309/kw/order%20automation)'.

Basically, you will use any of the variables mentioned above to send data you know will let you associate the returned visitor with an order/membership/whatever in your database/cookie/xml file/etc.

The variable you use will need to be sent in the form (all PayPal button's are forms) to PayPal when the buyer is redirected there, or else PayPal won't be able to send it back.

The order management product you pick, rm=2/[PDT](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_html_paymentdatatransfer)/[IPN](https://www.paypal.com/ipn), or a combination of these, will determine how you read the data. PDT/rm=2 is when the customer is returned, if they return. IPN is guaranteed, but may not occur before your visitor visits the page you want to check for the variable on.

Comment: The Order Management Guide solved the problem :) MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

While the [Order Management Guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/en_US/files/developer/PP_OrderMgmt_IntegrationGuide.pdf) is the formal/proper answer, for my use case, the short answer is to include another `<input>` in the `<form>` code PayPal provides, populate it (with JavaScript, erb, PHP, whatever).  This custom data then shows up in the transaction details you can see and download via the PayPal dashboard (though not in the payment notification email.)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<%= custom_data %>">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

FYI, this data is visible and spoofable, so you don't want to send secret data, you'd want it to be something that a buyer wouldn't want to spoof, like the `user_id` associated with the transaction.

This data is also sent with the IPN, if you use that... but for my use case, finding it in the transaction details was enough.

Comment: Does anyone know if you can use multiple "custom" fields?

Comment: I don't think so, however, you can pass encoded data (CSV or JSON) to embed multiple values.